# PHP: How to excute query without form postback?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form in which i want to do the validations. But there is a field which i want to validate writing a query. I dont want the form to postback because after postback all the values filled in the form are lost. Is there any way i can write a query without postback or if i have to postback how to retain the values ? Please help

Comment: What do you mean when you say "postback"?

Answer (score 3):

If you use AJAX (jQuery), you can post an XML Request without refreshing the browser, if this is what you need.
For this, just create a form with some textfields and a submit button, give everything an ID and add an click-Listener for the button:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php_file_to_execute.php',
        data: {username: name},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == "1") {
                document.write("Success");   
            } else {
                document.write("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If the user clicks on the button with the "submit-button"-ID, this function is called. Then you send the value of the textfield using POST to the php_file_to_execute.php. Inside this .php-File, you can validate the username and output theresult:

```
if($_POST['username'] != "Neha Raje") {
    echo "0";
} else {
    echo "1";
}
```

I hope that I could help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rephrase what you wrote, its a bit unclear. FYI I do it like this;

```
<form method="post">
Text 1: <input type="text" name="form[text1]" value="<?=$form["text1"]?>" size="5" /><br />
Text 2: <input type="text" name="form[text2]" value="<?=$form["text2"]?>" size="5" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Data" />
</form>
```

And when I am processing the data, it's like this;

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
 $i = $_POST["form"];
 if ($i["text1"] or ..... ) { $error = "Something is wrong."; }
 if ($i["text2"] and ..... ) { $error = "Maybe right."; }

 if (!$error) {
  /*
   * We should do something here, but if you don't want to return to the same
   * form, you should definitely post a header() or something like that here.
   */
   header ("Location: /"); exit;
 }
 //
}

if (!$_POST["form"] and !$_GET["id"]) {
} else {
 $form = $_POST["form"];
}
?>
```

By this method, the values are not lost *unless* you set them to get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `$.post()` method as:

```
$('#my_submit_button').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var username = $('#username').val();
  $.post('validate.php', {username: username, my_submit_button: 1}, function(response){
   console.log(response); //response contain either "true" or "false" bool value 
  });
});
```

In validate.php get the username from your form asynchronously as like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['my_submit_button']) && $_POST['my_submit_button'] == 1 && isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != "") {

  // now here you can check your validations with $_POST['username']
  // after checking validations, return or echo appropriate boolean value like:
  // if(some-condition) echo true;
  // else echo false;

}
```

**Note**: Please consider knowing security-related vulnerabilities and other issues before using AJAX for executing database-altering scripts.